# Javascript encapsulation with expressions and closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I explore expressions and closures in javascript and i don't understand something.
I code two objects X and Y, i call the second object in the first and when it run if 
the objects have methods with same names, the next call of a method of the first object 
will be set to the method of the class of the second object.

```
( function( prototypeY ) {
    Y = ( function() {
        return function() {
            prototypeY.getName = function() {
                return "Y";
            };
        };
    })();
})( Object.prototype );

( function( prototypeX ) {
    X = ( function() {
        return function() {
            prototypeX.getName = function() {
                return "X";
            };
            prototypeX.getObject = function() {
                return new Y();
            };
        };
    })();
})( Object.prototype );

var objectX = new X();
var objectY = objectX.getObject(); //new Y()

alert( objectX.getName() ); // "Y"
```

i hope someone can explain me why and show me how to transform it in order to make this works

Comment: Keep it simple always. You don't need closures here at all.

Comment: What is your end goal? I can't work out what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want to establish some kind of inheritance hierarchy between `X` and `Y`?

Comment: How can i call the Y constructor in the X constructor and not to touch the prototype of X ?

Comment: Maybe the following answer can explain constructor functions and prototype: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing `"Y"` at the end is that you're overwriting the value you've put on `Object.prototype.getName`. When you call `new X()`, you're putting a `getName` property on `prototypeX`, which is a reference to (not a copy of) `Object.prototype`. So now `Object.prototype` has a `getName` which returns `"X"`. When you call `objectX.getObject()`, that's doing a `new Y()` call, which involves setting `getName` on `prototypeY`. `prototypeY` is also a reference to (not a copy of) `Object.prototype`, and so the value set by `Y` overwrites the value set by `X`.

The solution is *don't change `Object.prototype`*. Adding properties to `Object.prototype` is generally a bad idea. Adding *enumerable* properties (ones that show up in `for...in` loops) like your `getName` and `getObject` properties is **always** a bad idea.

Below you've said:

> I have a background in java and i would like to do that :
>
> `class Y, class X ( public Y getY() ( return new Y )`

That's *dramatically* simpler than what you have:

```
// Constructor function X
function X() {
}

// Add some things to the prototype it assigns objects created via `new`.
// Note that the object `X.prototype` refers to has `Object.prototype` as
// its prototype, that's already been set up for you.
X.prototype.getName = function() {
    return "X";
};
X.prototype.getObject = function() {
    return new Y();
};

// Constructor function Y    
function Y() {
}

// Add something to the prototype it assigns objects created via `new`.
// `Y.prototype` also refers to an object that uses `Object.prototype` as
// its prototype.
Y.prototype.getName = function() {
    return "Y";
};
```

Or if you want to use named functions for debugging purposes, or have information that is only available to code within the various functions related to `X` and `Y` (like statics in Java), you might do this:

```
// Define X
var X = function() {
    // If you had `var` statements here, the vars would be accessible to
    // the code within this anonymous function, kind of like Java static
    // variables within a class.

    // Constructor function X
    function X() {
    }

    // Add some things to the prototype it assigns objects created via `new`.
    // Note that the object `X.prototype` refers to has `Object.prototype` as
    // its prototype, that's already been set up for you.
    X.prototype.getName = X$getName;
    function X$getName() { // There's nothing special about this name
        return "X";
    }
    X.prototype.getObject = X$getObject;
    function X$getObject() {
        return new Y();
    }

    return X;
}(); // () at the end runs the above, assigns its result to our variable

// Define Y
var Y = function() {
    // Constructor function Y    
    function Y() {
    }

    // Add something to the prototype it assigns objects created via `new`.
    // `Y.prototype` also refers to an object that uses `Object.prototype` as
    // its prototype.
    Y.prototype.getName = Y$getName;
    function Y$getName() {
        return "Y";
    }

    return Y;
}();
```

---

At one point I thought your goal was to set up an inheritance hierarchy where `Y` is derived from `X`, using constructor functions. According to your comment you don't, but I'll leave this in case others do want to. Here's how you'd do that hierarchy:

```
// Set up X
function X() {
}
X.prototype.getName = function() { 
    return "X";
};
X.prototype.getObject = function() { 
    return new Y(); // <== But this is usually a bad idea from an OOP perspective,
                    //     base classes really shouldn't refer to subclasses
};
X.prototype.answer = function() { // Something for Y objects to inherit
    return 42;
};

// Set up Y, where Y objects have a prototype that in turn has X.prototype
function Y() {
    X.call(this); // Chain to base constructor function
}
Y.prototype = Object.create(X.prototype);
Y.prototype.constructor = Y;
Y.prototype.getName = function() { 
    return "Y";
};

var x = new X();
console.log(x.getName()); // "X"
console.log(x.answer());  // "42"

var y = new Y();
console.log(x.getName()); // "Y", because Y overrides the X version of `getName`
console.log(x.answer());  // "42", because Y inherits the X version of `answer`
```

`Object.create` was added in ES5, but can be partially shimmed/polyfilled for older browsers (sufficient for our use above); here's [MDN's version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill) but with a different name for a variable where the MDN version used `Object`, which makes **no** sense:

```
if (typeof Object.create != 'function') {
  Object.create = (function() {
    var ctor = function() {};
    return function (prototype) {
      if (arguments.length > 1) {
        throw Error('Second argument not supported');
      }
      if (typeof prototype != 'object') {
        throw TypeError('Argument must be an object');
      }
      ctor.prototype = prototype;
      var result = new ctor();
      ctor.prototype = null;
      return result;
    };
  })();
}
```

Comment: So i must clone Object.prototype when i use it but you say it's a bad idea thus how can i replace Object.prototype to make this works

Comment: @user3511595: Again: What's your end goal? Nothing in your code is "cloning" `Object.prototype`, and you almost certainly don't want to anyway (instead, you probably want to make it the prototype of another object).

Comment: I have a background in java and i would like to do that :

Comment: class Y, class X ( public Y getY() ( return new Y )

Comment: That's even simpler than what I thought you wanted to do (there's no inheritance between X and Y there), I'll update the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to call new and not to modify the container ?

Comment: @user3511595: What do you mean by "modify the container"? In the normal case, using `new` doesn't modify anything I'd call a "container."